# Finding "~/Library/Application Support" from C++?

Tags: c++, macos

I've written a GTKmm application and I'm trying to create some OS X enhancements.  I'd like to store my configuration file in the Application Support/myApp folder, however, I can't figure out the proper way to locate this folder.

I've tried looking through the Core Foundation library (that I'm using to get my myApp.app path) but I can't find anything.

Comment: the good solution is a Objective-C wrapper like the one recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634632/accessing-standard-directories-on-os-x-with-c (wrapper around (NSURL*)applicationDataDirectory from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Proper way to do it in C/C++:

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

FSRef ref;
OSType folderType = kApplicationSupportFolderType;
char path[PATH_MAX];

FSFindFolder( kUserDomain, folderType, kCreateFolder, &ref );

FSRefMakePath( &ref, (UInt8*)&path, PATH_MAX );

// You now have ~/Library/Application Support stored in 'path'
```

Naturally, those are very old APIs and their use is no longer recommended by Apple. Despite that it gets the job done if you want to avoid Objective-C completely in your codebase.

Comment: #include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

and I had to use PATH_MAX instead of MAX_PATH.

Comment: But that API is considered deprecated. You won't be able to put your app to Mac App store. Use Objective-C++ wrapper instead.

Comment: @AlexanderShishenko: Maybe you're confusing deprecated APIs and **private** APIs? AFAIK, Apple isn't going to reject your app because you use deprecated APIs (in and of themselves), but they could reject it if you use undocumented/private APIs. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7909986/277952

Comment: Compile fails on Xcode 11: 'FSFindFolder' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.8

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the function to use for this is [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/StandardDirectories.html) (or some other functions listed on the same page) with `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` as the argument.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot figure out how to use that in C++.  The Cocoa.h file is written in Obj-C so I can't include it in my C++ app.

Comment: @baubie: Could you write an Objective C file that wraps the API?  It does appear there is a Carbon equivalent to the function, `FindFolder`, but it is marked as legacy (http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/folder_manager.pdf)

Comment: There is a wrapper in one of the answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634632/accessing-standard-directories-on-os-x-with-c

Answer (score 2):

In BSD Unix, included in OS-X, you can get the home directory of the user running the program with this:

```
struct passwd *p = getpwuid(getuid());  /* defined in pwd.h, and requires sys/types.h */ 
char *home = p->pw_dir;
```

Using this, you can then construct the path using this in place of ~

```
char *my_app_name = "WHATEVER";
char app_support[MAXPATHLEN];  /* defined in sys/param.h */
snprintf(app_support,MAXPATHLEN,"%s/Library/Application Support/%s", home, my_app_name);
```

Comment: Apple advices against hardcoding the `~/Library/Application Support/` path. For one thing, it will not work with application sandboxing in their newer OSes.

Comment: @Aeyoun - Do you have a link to what _is_ recommended for getting this path?

Answer (score 2):

## `sysdir` for macOS 10.12+

For macOS 10.12 and later, Apple provide the [`sysdir.h`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sysdir/) API:

```cpp
#include <sysdir.h>  // for sysdir_start_search_path_enumeration
#include <glob.h>    // for glob needed to expand ~ to user dir

std::string expandTilde(const char* str) {
    if (!str) return {};

    glob_t globbuf;
    if (glob(str, GLOB_TILDE, nullptr, &globbuf) == 0) {
        std::string result(globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
        globfree(&globbuf);
        return result;
    } else {
        throw std::exception("Unable to expand tilde");
    }
}

std::string settingsPath(const char* str) {
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    auto state = sysdir_start_search_path_enumeration(SYSDIR_DIRECTORY_APPLICATION_SUPPORT,
                                                      SYSDIR_DOMAIN_MASK_USER);
    if ((state = sysdir_get_next_search_path_enumeration(state, path))) {
        return expandTilde(path);
    } else {
        throw std::exception("Failed to get settings folder");
    }
}
```

`sysdir` replaces the now deprecated `NSSystemDirectories` and `FindFolder` approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is not application support but you probably don't want to store files there anyways. Instead use the directory that you get from calling "HOME":

You can use the C-function getenv: `char *home = getenv("HOME");`

and to get the C++ string use: `string(home)`