# Will Apple accept Apps with deprecated code?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

Will Apple accept Apps for selling inside the App-Store with deprecated code?

Comment: It's a human process. You can't say. If the code is deprecated, replace it with the correct implementation.... A better question would be to post what you're trying to do and post the code you currently implement, and ask for a viable alternative.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes. Deprecated doesn't mean unavailable or disallowed; if it did, it would be called something else, or those methods would simply be removed from the API.

Deprecation is a way of letting you know that you should start transitioning your existing codebase. The rule of thumb should be: don't *add* code that you know uses deprecated functionality, that's just silly. Be aware as you work on older code bases that deprecated methods you were using may need your attention sooner or later.

One of the risks of continuing to use deprecated methods is that they may be more primitive and dangerous than newer versions, may not take into account all current OS realities, and possibly less well tested by Apple over time. You run the risk of having this bite you even before they vanish from the framework.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Apple will accept your app assuming everything else goes right. Deprecated doesn't mean the app will not work. It's just a way of telling you that you should start using newer code as opposed to older code. The older code will be removed from the API eventually, so it's better to fix it sooner than to try to build your app and find out that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I've used the following deprecated code (the init method is deprecated):

```
[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

in an app recently that was approved.

Answer (score -6):

Well... It depends. In most cases probably not, but I don't run the app store so I'm not sure.