# Using deprecated methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Apple accept Apps with deprecated code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909986/will-apple-accept-apps-with-deprecated-code)

I am developping an iPhone application and i am using a method like this :

```
- (NSString*)udid
{
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    return [device.uniqueIdentifier stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
}
```

But i have seen that the "uniqueIdentifier" is deprecated.The problem it's working fine, and i would like to know what's will happen if i will post my app in the store like this ( with the use of the deprecated method)

thanks for your answers.

Comment: there were news recently (well, almost a month ago) that apple is rejecting apps who's sending plain text UDIDs:  http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/ there are also quite some open source solutions for replacement of the udid (e.g. generating tokens based on MAC address).

Comment: I just wanted to add another point to the answer from @user1260708, that "Apps Using UDIDs Being Rejected By Apple". Here is a link and an alternative: http://maniacdev.com/2012/03/apps-using-udids-being-rejected-by-apple-heres-how-to-generate-replacements-quickly/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+maniacdev+%28iPhone%2C+iOS+4%2C+iPad+SDK+Development+Tutorial+and+Programming+Tips%29&utm_content=Google+Reader

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't use deprecated apis, as they are liable to be removed from future versions. Also, APIs are generally deprecated because they are obsolete or sub-optimal, and there's usually a newer, better way of doing whatever you're trying to do.

In your case, *definitely* don't, for this reason:
http://gigaom.com/apple/apple-cracks-down-on-udid-use/

I believe the popular alternative is to create a UUID (which will be unique, but not tied to the device) on first run and save it to refer to on subsequent runs. It's been quite extensively talked about if you google it.