# Accessing Standard Directories on OS X with C++

Tags: c++, macos

What is the modern, standard, canonical method for accessing standard directories on OS X from C++, such as `~/Library/Application Support` or `~/Library/Preferences`?

I've seen mention of the use [CoreServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123361/finding-library-application-support-from-c), but it's also mentioned that it's deprecated and I'm having trouble finding the documentation that will allow me to do more than just paste the code in.

I've found mention of using Objective C++, but most information about that option revolves around calling C++ code from Objective C, and again, Apple's documentation on it seems rather sparse, or at least I've not had success finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following Technical Q & A that addresses tilde expansion in an environment where you won't want to pull in the NS namespaces:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1549/_index.html

I have not encountered built-in CoreFoundation calls that are similar to NSString's expandTildeAtPath. As for the CoreServices example you mentioned, which included FsRefs. These were older Carbon calls and objects to work with system files. Those have been deprecated, not CoreFoundation.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and while that worked, the inelegance of it simply turned me off. I decided to go with Objective C++, which pretty much allows me to use this C++ API while staying out of C++ as much as possible. While I'm still not sure if `[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains]` or using `NSURL` is best (I'm using `NSFileManager` for now), at least it's working with simple code instead of the Core Foundation workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is the little-known `NSSystemDirectories.h` (at `/usr/include/NSSystemDirectories.h`) header that has existed on every version of OS X I checked all the way back to OS X 10.3. It's part of libc: http://opensource.apple.com//source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/include/NSSystemDirectories.h

That provides a C API, though it's not too difficult to create an Objective-C++ wrapper: create a pure C++ interface and in the implementation, use Objective-C.

FolderManager.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
namespace fm {
    enum {
        NSApplicationDirectory = 1,
        NSDemoApplicationDirectory,
        NSDeveloperApplicationDirectory,
        NSAdminApplicationDirectory,
        NSLibraryDirectory,
        NSDeveloperDirectory,
        NSUserDirectory,
        NSDocumentationDirectory,
        NSDocumentDirectory,
        NSCoreServiceDirectory,
        NSAutosavedInformationDirectory = 11,
        NSDesktopDirectory = 12,
        NSCachesDirectory = 13,
        NSApplicationSupportDirectory = 14,
        NSDownloadsDirectory = 15,
        NSInputMethodsDirectory = 16,
        NSMoviesDirectory = 17,
        NSMusicDirectory = 18,
        NSPicturesDirectory = 19,
        NSPrinterDescriptionDirectory = 20,
        NSSharedPublicDirectory = 21,
        NSPreferencePanesDirectory = 22,
        NSApplicationScriptsDirectory = 23,
        NSItemReplacementDirectory = 99,
        NSAllApplicationsDirectory = 100,
        NSAllLibrariesDirectory = 101,
        NSTrashDirectory = 102
    };
    typedef unsigned long SearchPathDirectory;

    enum {
        NSUserDomainMask = 1,       // user's home directory --- place to install user's personal items (~)
        NSLocalDomainMask = 2,      // local to the current machine --- place to install items available to everyone on this machine (/Library)
        NSNetworkDomainMask = 4,    // publically available location in the local area network --- place to install items available on the network (/Network)
        NSSystemDomainMask = 8,     // provided by Apple, unmodifiable (/System)
        NSAllDomainsMask = 0x0ffff  // all domains: all of the above and future items
    };
    typedef unsigned long SearchPathDomainMask;

    class FolderManager {
        public:

        FolderManager();
        ~FolderManager();

        const char *pathForDirectory(SearchPathDirectory directory, SearchPathDomainMask domainMask);
        const char *pathForDirectoryAppropriateForItemAtPath(SearchPathDirectory directory, SearchPathDomainMask domainMask, const char *itemPath, bool create = false);

        private:
            void *m_autoreleasePool;
    };
};
```

FolderManager.**mm** (note the filename extension)

```
#include "FolderManager.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

using namespace fm;

FolderManager::FolderManager() {
    m_autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
}

FolderManager::~FolderManager() {
    [(NSAutoreleasePool *)m_autoreleasePool release];
}

const char * FolderManager::pathForDirectory(SearchPathDirectory directory, SearchPathDomainMask domainMask) {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *URLs = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)directory inDomains:domainMask];
    if (URLs.count == 0) return NULL;

    NSURL *URL = [URLs objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = URL.path;

    // `fileSystemRepresentation` on an `NSString` gives a path suitable for POSIX APIs
    return path.fileSystemRepresentation;
}

const char * FolderManager::pathForDirectoryAppropriateForItemAtPath(SearchPathDirectory directory,
 SearchPathDomainMask domainMask, const char *itemPath, bool create) {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *nsPath = [fileManager stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:itemPath length:strlen(itemPath)];
    NSURL *itemURL = (nsPath ? [NSURL fileURLWithPath:nsPath] : nil);

    NSURL *URL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)directory
                       inDomain:domainMask
              appropriateForURL:itemURL
                         create:create error:NULL];
    return URL.path.fileSystemRepresentation;
}
```

Note that this should be compiled without Automatic Reference Counting enabled (or at least, that's how I was using it; it's possible that it will also work with ARC, but I haven't tested that). It's important to create and release an `NSAutoreleasePool` in the constructor and destructor, respectively, otherwise, you may get memory leaks and warnings in the Console to that effect (unless an `NSAutoreleasePool` has been created elsewhere for you)**.

To use it, something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *folderPath = NULL;
    FolderManager folderManager;
    folderPath = (char *)folderManager.pathForDirectory(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask);
    printf("folderPath == %s\n", folderPath);

    folderPath = (char *)folderManager.pathForDirectory(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSLocalDomainMask);
    printf("folderPath == %s\n", folderPath);

    folderPath = (char *)folderManager.pathForDirectory(NSTrashDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask);
    printf("folderPath == %s\n", folderPath);

    if (argc > 1) {
        folderPath = (char *)folderManager.pathForDirectoryAppropriateForItemAtPath(NSTrashDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, argv[1]);
        printf("folderPath == %s\n", folderPath);

        folderPath = (char *)folderManager.pathForDirectoryAppropriateForItemAtPath(NSItemReplacementDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, argv[1], true);
        printf("folderPath == %s\n", folderPath);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my machine, passing it an argument of `/Volumes/Untitled3/folder/testFile.chm`, it will output the following:

```
folderPath == /Users/mdouma46/Library/Application Support
folderPath == /Library/Application Support
folderPath == /Users/mdouma46/.Trash
folderPath == /Volumes/Untitled 3/.Trashes/501
folderPath == /Volumes/Untitled 3/.TemporaryItems/folders.501/TemporaryItems/(A Document Being Saved By findFolder)
```

**Regarding the memory management comment about the importance of an `NSAutoreleasePool`: I tested it here in OS X Yosemite, Xcode 7.2.1, by commenting out the creation of the `NSAutoreleasePool`, and for the life of me, I cannot get any errors logged to console, so I'm not sure what's going on.

What I was expecting was the result I got when I compiled it in Xcode 3.2.6 in OS X 10.6:

```
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10010c6d0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10010c820 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111540 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111710 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111770 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111a20 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111a60 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111d10 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111ac0 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111c20 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111de0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
findFolder[300] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111cb0 of class NSConcreteData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
folderPath == /Users/mdouma46/Library/Application Support
```

This happens because many of the Objective-C calls return autoreleased objects: `NSFileManager`'s `URLsForDirectory:inDomain:` returns an autoreleased array of `NSURL`s. Calling `NSURL`'s `path` method returns (creates) autoreleased `NSString`s (actually, the `NSPathStore2` private subclass), etc...

Comment: I don't know if this is another question, but when you call 'pathForDirectory' on your class instance, why would the autorelease pool be implicitly used for any allocations?

Comment: since 10.12 :  "This API has been fully replaced by API in sysdir.h."

Answer (score 0):

## `sysdir` for macOS 10.12+

For macOS 10.12 and later, Apple provide the [`sysdir.h`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sysdir/) API:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <sysdir.h>

char path[PATH_MAX];
sysdir_search_path_enumeration_state state = sysdir_start_search_path_enumeration(dir, domainMask);
while ( (state = sysdir_get_next_search_path_enumeration(state, path)) != 0 ) {
    // Handle directory path
}
```

`sysdir` replaces the now deprecated `NSSystemDirectories` and `FindFolder` approaches.